# Featured Image on WP

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have a little problem... when I want to show the featured image on my posts, the chosen size isn't working (the photo is shown in it's own size). And I want the featured Image to be shown in the same width as the post total width but I have no clue! ([THIS IS THE LINK TO THE WEBSITE](http://demilovatoonline.com/danithemes))

This is the code I'm using in the PHP section

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); set_post_thumbnail_size(640, 205);
```

As you can see, the size I've chosen is 640x205, but when I add :

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
```

When I add that code under the post title code, the featured Image is shown in it's 'own' size and it's not shown as the post total width.

What can I do?

Comment: If you have set the featured image before implementing the size, you need to regenerate the image again https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/.

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
the_post_thumbnail( array(width,height) );
```

as width and height are your values.

Comment: Still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

In your theme function.php under this function

function twentythirteen_setup(){

add_image_size( 'My-Size', Width, height, TRUE );

}

```
the_post_thumbnail('My-Size');
```

Note :: After adding the add_image_size function please upload your all images again or use "[Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/)" plugin after regenerate images you can see the images in your actual size which you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?php 
       if(has_post_thumbnail()) {  
          the_post_thumbnail(array(350,300));
        } else {
          echo '<img src="'.get_bloginfo("template_url").'/images/no-image.jpg" width="500" height="393"/>';
        }
?>
```